# LLDB - automatically step, and print list of lines, until a breakpoint

Tags: lldb

I'd like to keeping on executing the following command:

```
(lldb) s
```

until it reach a breakpoint. Or simply when it reaches some function (eg. read())

While this is happening, I'd like to save the list of line numbers (and the full path of the files) in the order that they were executed. So for eg. save to a file (LOG.csv) that looks like this:

```
Number;LineNumber;FilePath
1;1080;/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/shell.c
2;1082;/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/shell.c
3;1083;/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/shell.c
4;40;/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/readline.c 
5;71;/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/readline.c 
6;72;/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/readline.c
```

**Note the full path of the files are needed. See row 4 VS row 5 which are actually from 2 different files with the same name.
**Number refers to the order of execution.

The format will be something like above, but preferably this can be customised.

**If possible, I'd also like to run the program first up to some breakpoint, and then step until another breakpoint.

How should this be done? Can I use the Python API, or C API? Other means are also possible.

For answers on the API, do mention which class and methods to use for (1) stepping (2) retrieving the current line (3) retrieve the full file path (4) checking that the function read() has been reached

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is to use Python directly in the Script Interpreter REPL (enter this with the `script` command in lldb).  Then in the Python REPL, you can write a while loop that does whatever printing you want to do, checks your stop condition, and if it is not satisfied, calls SBThread.StepInto or StepOver on the thread you are following.

More info on the lldb Python API's is here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api.html

The one thing you'll want to be aware of is that lldb's debugger has two running modes "synchronous" and "asynchronous".  If the debugger is in "synchronous" mode than any command that makes the debugee run waits to return until the debugee stops for some reason.  In "asynchronous" mode, the "SBThread.StepInto", "SBThread.StepOver", etc. methods return immediately and you use lldb's event system to be notified of stops.  The former is much more convenient for your task, so at the beginning of your `script` session just do:

```
>>> lldb.debugger.SetAsync(False)
```

You can also package this logic in a Python based command if that makes using it more convenient.

The fancier way to do this is to use an lldb "scripted step" plan.  There are a few examples of ways to use that here:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/python/scripted_step.py

The header at the beginning of the file has some explanation of how this works, and there's more docs here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#using-the-python-api-to-create-custom-stepping-logic

Though the setup is a little daunting, since you are just replying to a few simple messages, once you figure out how it works, the implementation is often pretty simple in the end.

One other thing to remember is that all the code that runs in lldb's python interpreter shared the lldb console.  So if you invoke the pdb debugger in some code you've written, you'll get the pdb prompt in the console and can view variables and step along through your python code.  E.g. insert:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

to set a breakpoint somewhere in your code.

Comment: thank you @Jim Ingham. can you provide advice on which class and methods to use to retrieve the current line and file, and to check that the function read() has been reached?

Comment: When you stop, find the thread you are tracing (remember that multiple threads may stop at any given time, so store the thread index and then re-look it up with  SBProcess.thread[IDX].  Then get frame 0 from it (SBThread.frame is an array of the frames in order, so `thread.frames[0]`is the current frame).  Get the `addr` property from the SBFrame.  That will be an SBAddress, which has properties for the line_entry and function.  That should do what you need.