# LLDB Automatic Stepping Through Program With Python Returning Steps/Lines That Don't Appear Manually

Tags: lldb

Following [LLDB - automatically step, and print list of lines, until a breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298178/lldb-automatically-step-and-print-list-of-lines-until-a-breakpoint), I was able to successfully write a csv file of the line numbers and file names of each step when stepping through my program. However, I find my output very strange. My CSV file contains lines that dun appear when I step through manually. For example:

```
431,/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/input.c
435,/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/input.c
132,/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/input.c
132,/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/input.c
452,/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/input.c
462,/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/lib/readline/input.c
```

For eg., if you look at input.c:

```
int
rl_getc (stream)
     FILE *stream;
{
  int result;
  unsigned char c;

  while (1)
    {
#if defined (__MINGW32__)

...
```

Line 462 is actually this line:

```
{
```

Which is not a line that is usually stopped at.

This is my Python code:

```
import lldb
import csv

lldb.debugger.SetAsync(False)
i = 1
while i:
    with open('Z.csv', mode='a') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        l = lldb.thread.frames[0].addr.GetLineEntry().line
        fn = str(lldb.thread.frames[0].addr.GetLineEntry().GetFileSpec())
        employee_writer.writerow([l, fn])
        lldb.thread.StepInto()
        i=i+1
```

In lldb, I ran the script command, and then pasted the above code in the embedded Python interpreter.

This is how it would be like if I had manually step through the code:

```
Process 14194 launched: '/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/bash' (x86_64)
bash-3.2$ bash was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c9a4 bash`rl_read_key at input.c:421 [opt]
   418  {
   419    int c;
   420  
-> 421    rl_key_sequence_length++;
   422  
   423    if (rl_pending_input)
   424      {
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c9bd bash`rl_read_key at input.c:423 [opt]
   420  
   421    rl_key_sequence_length++;
   422  
-> 423    if (rl_pending_input)
   424      {
   425        c = rl_pending_input;
   426        rl_clear_pending_input ();
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c9df bash`rl_read_key at input.c:431 [opt]
   428    else
   429      {
   430        /* If input is coming from a macro, then use that. */
-> 431        if (c = _rl_next_macro_key ())
   432      return (c);
   433  
   434        /* If the user has an event function, then call it periodically. */
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007bf94 bash`_rl_next_macro_key at macro.c:105 [opt]
   102  {
   103    int c;
   104  
-> 105    if (rl_executing_macro == 0)
   106      return (0);
   107  
   108    if (rl_executing_macro[executing_macro_index] == 0)
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c0a0 bash`_rl_next_macro_key at macro.c:122 [opt]
   119  #else
   120    return (rl_executing_macro[executing_macro_index++]);
   121  #endif
-> 122  }
   123  
   124  /* Save the currently executing macro on a stack of saved macros. */
   125  void
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c9e4 bash`rl_read_key at input.c:431 [opt]
   428    else
   429      {
   430        /* If input is coming from a macro, then use that. */
-> 431        if (c = _rl_next_macro_key ())
   432      return (c);
   433  
   434        /* If the user has an event function, then call it periodically. */
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007ca01 bash`rl_read_key at input.c:435 [opt]
   432      return (c);
   433  
   434        /* If the user has an event function, then call it periodically. */
-> 435        if (rl_event_hook)
   436      {
   437        while (rl_event_hook && rl_get_char (&c) == 0)
   438          {
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007cdd8 bash`rl_read_key at input.c:451 [opt]
   448      }
   449        else
   450      {
-> 451        if (rl_get_char (&c) == 0)
   452          c = (*rl_getc_function) (rl_instream);
   453      }
   454      }
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007cdd8 bash`rl_read_key [inlined] rl_get_char at input.c:132 [opt]
   129  rl_get_char (key)
   130       int *key;
   131  {
-> 132    if (push_index == pop_index)
   133      return (0);
   134  
   135    *key = ibuffer[pop_index++];
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007cde7 bash`rl_read_key at input.c:452 [opt]
   449        else
   450      {
   451        if (rl_get_char (&c) == 0)
-> 452          c = (*rl_getc_function) (rl_instream);
   453      }
   454      }
   455  
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c4a0 bash`rl_getc(stream=0x00007fff8abf8110) at input.c:462 [opt]
   459  int
   460  rl_getc (stream)
   461       FILE *stream;
-> 462  {
   463    int result;
   464    unsigned char c;
   465  
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) s
Process 14194 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x000000010007c4ad bash`rl_getc(stream=0x00007fff8abf8110) at input.c:472 [opt]
   469        if (isatty (fileno (stream)))
   470      return (getch ());
   471  #endif
-> 472        result = read (fileno (stream), &c, sizeof (unsigned char));
   473  
   474        if (result == sizeof (unsigned char))
   475      return (c);
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
```

What could be the reason why this happens? And is there a way to solve this problem?

EDIT:

After trying the following new code, I still have the same problematic output:

```
import lldb
import csv

lldb.debugger.SetAsync(False)
i = 1
while i:
    with open('Z.csv', mode='a') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        l = lldb.thread.frames[0].line_entry.line
        fn = str(lldb.thread.frames[0].line_entry.GetFileSpec())
        employee_writer.writerow([l, fn])
        lldb.thread.StepInto()
        i=I+1
```

EDIT 2:

This is how I obtained the executable that I ran lldb on:

First, downloaded this:
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.57.tar.gz

Then followed the instructions on:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Basic-Installation

That's how I got the file:
/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/bas

Which I executed lldb on.

These is the sequence of lldb commands I used from start to finish:

```
user$ lldb
(lldb) file /Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Current executable set to '/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/bash' (x86_64).
(lldb) breakpoint set -n main
Breakpoint 1: where = bash`main + 30 at shell.c:354, address = 0x000000010000152e
(lldb) run
Process 3118 launched: '/Users/user/Documents/zDEVELOP/bash-3.2.57/bash' (x86_64)
bash was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
Process 3118 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010000152e bash`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbffa70, env=0x00007ffeefbffa80) at shell.c:354 [opt]
   351  #endif
   352  
   353    /* Catch early SIGINTs. */
-> 354    code = setjmp (top_level);
   355    if (code)
   356      exit (2);
   357  
Target 0: (bash) stopped.
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
```

And then I executed the following code in the Python interpreter:

```
import lldb
import csv

lldb.debugger.SetAsync(False)
i = 1
while i:
    with open('Z.csv', mode='a') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        l = lldb.thread.frames[0].line_entry.line
        fn = str(lldb.thread.frames[0].line_entry.GetFileSpec())
        employee_writer.writerow([l, fn])
        lldb.thread.StepInto()
        i=I+1
```

Comment: Can you post the difference between the lines you stop at when you just do step on the command line, and when you run your script.  SBThread.StepInto is pretty much what the "step" command does, so they shouldn't be different.  The fact that line 662 has a line entry means that it will in general be a place lldb stops when stepping.  lldb just steps from line entry to line entry.

Comment: @Jim Ingham tq for reply. I have added what you requested. there is some matching in line numbers, but the order is all wrong.

Comment: Note first that you are stepping in optimized code, so the stepping order is not going to make sense compared to the source.  Also, when a function is inlined, there are generally two line table entries for the start of the inlining, one for the call site, and one for the beginning of the inlined function.  Step "fakes" stepping in from one to the other (you can see this in the step from 0x000000010007cdd8 to 0x000000010007cdd8 above.  But if you ask an address what its line entry is, we have to pick one - we pick the deepest.  That's why your printing shows 132 twice.

Comment: @Jim Ingham I see. is there anything I can do if I'd like an exact correspondence between my csv output and the manual output on the terminal?

Comment: You are printing `lldb.thread.frames[0].addr.GetLineEntry().line`  Instead, just do: `lldb.thread.frames[0].line_entry.line`.  That will report the "virtual" line entry when you are somewhere in a stack of nesting inlines.  Going from the frame to the PC address and then back to the line entry is what is erasing this information.

Comment: hi @JimIngham, I just tried what you suggested. but the output is exactly the same as before. I have pasted my new code in the post above. May I know how to solve this?

Comment: Most likely need to watch this happening to know what is going on.  If you have an example project that you can make available, can you file a bug at https://bugs.llvm.org with the project, how you build it, and how ran it to stop wherever you did to start your scripted stepping.

Comment: hi @JimIngham, Actually this project is really just GNU bash, and I followed the instructions to compile on MacOS 10.13.6 from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Basic-Installation. I simply downloaded their their project folder from their website. I have also tried to file a bug as per your request but they require me to email in for an account first, so I emailed in with the project folder for your convenience from my work email humanities...gmail.com

Comment: If the project is available, just tell me what hash you have so we're working with the same thing, and where you were stopped and how you stopped there (so we'll follow the same path...).

Comment: ok @JimIngham, please see EDIT 2 in the post above.

Comment: hi @JimIngham, is the info in EDIT 2 ok? Is it sufficient?

Comment: hi @JimIngham, I just modified the post again under EDIT 2 to indicate how I obtained the source files, and how I compiled them. Is it ok?

Comment: Your info is fine, but I've been too busy to look at them yet.  I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: ok @JimIngham do update me when you can tqtq

Comment: @JimIngham do u have any headway on this? if no, I am thinking of using Expect (https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) to automate lldb and hopefully achieve the same goal

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda slammed right now...

Comment: hi @JimIngham, I am also not making progress with Expect. If you are available, do assist. Regards